# We know that String will store in SCP in the same way String[] also store in SCP? and what about ArrayList<String>?

Tags: java, out-of-memory

We know that a `String` will be stored in SCP (String Constant Pool) area:
**1.** in the same way `String[]` is also stored in SCP? i mean each array contains a `String`, so again this will be stored in SCP?
**2.** and what about `ArrayList(String)` ? i mean each arraylist contains a `String`, so again this will be stored in SCP?

In our project we are facing OutOfMemory. we are having more than 1000+ `String[]`.
 ***Each time values for String[] are different. So Huge no of objects are getting created  in SCP (guessing)*** 
We want to change this to `ArrayList(String)` to reduce memory. If again `ArrayList(String)`, each String gets stored in SCP area, then there is no use of changing from `String[]` to `ArrayList(String)`

Please explain in detail. Your response is valuable.

Comment: Are you sure you're getting the `OutOfMemoryException` because of too many `String` objects?

Comment: *We know that String will store in SCP*: no. Every String is not stored in the constant pool. Only String **literals** and Strings on which intern() has been called. The other String instances are in the heap like any other object.

Comment: No. Using ArrayList will not fix the problem. Actually, it will make your program less efficient. Why?, well because arrays have less overhead in terms of operations performed to maintain state. Lists have their own overhead. PS : Don't edit questions to ask answers.

Comment: ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>(); al.add("one"); al.add("two"); i am asking like above "one" and "two" will go and store in scp? or it will store in heap

Answer (score 2):

No. All Strings will not be stored in String Constant Pool. Only String literals and interned Strings will be stored there.

```
String s = "abc"; // stores "abc" in the SCP if it is not already present.

String s1= "abc";// stores "abc" in the SCP if it is not already present.
String s2="abc";// Doesn't store "abc" into the String pool as it is already present.
String s3=s1+s2;  // "abcabc" goes on heap
```

`String[]` is just an array that holds references to String objects.
So, I think there is some other problem somewhere else. 
Also, from Oracle doc :

> In JDK 7, interned strings are no longer allocated in the permanent
>   generation of the Java heap, but are instead allocated in the main
>   part of the Java heap (known as the young and old generations), along
>   with the other objects created by the application. This change will
>   result in more data residing in the main Java heap, and less data in
>   the permanent generation, and thus may require heap sizes to be
>   adjusted. Most applications will see only relatively small differences
>   in heap usage due to this change, but larger applications that load
>   many classes or make heavy use of the String.intern() method will see
>   more significant differences.

Comment: So, if i create a ArrayList(String) object. then each individual String created from ArrayList will go and store in SCP?

Comment: @frq - No. Only String literals and interned Strings are stored in SCP. ArrayList will only contain references.

Comment: can you please re-read my question. ArrayList al = new ArrayList<String>();
al.add("one");
al.add("two");

i am asking like above "one" and "two" will go and store in scp? or it will store in heap

Comment: @frq - they will go into the SCP. :)

Comment: I got info like ArrayList will use Object[] internally and will store in Heap, Not in SCP. Are you sure about your statement that above "one" and "two" will go and store in SCP? If so any link or confirmation can you provide? Because i have to do lot with this

Comment: @frq - yes. "one", "two" three" will go into SCP. and new String objects will be created on heap as well. In Java all String literals will go onto heap.

Answer (score 1):

Its the String literals that are stored in pool. Rest for all other questions that you have, its just a reference. So String[] holds reference to String Objects which include pooled objects as well. Similarly ArrayList will hold the reference.

Changing [] to ArrayList wont make a difference.

Rather changing these String to StringBuffer/builder will, as basic operations like +(concat) doesnot create a new object all together.

Comment: So, if i create a ArrayList(String) object. then each individual String created from ArrayList will go and store in SCP?

Comment: NO, it depends on the way you create those String. String which are created as String s = "frq" are stored in SCP, String which are created as String s = new String("fqr") are stored in heap, however they can be stored in SCP by calling s.intern() not by default.